# Hide div when "animate-delay: 1s;" still ongoing and display after the delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

**I am using the following CSS file** in order to add some animations to my website that I'm building:
http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/scrolling.html

Its concept is pretty simple - You add class names to your div to have it animated when you get to it when you scroll the page up/down.

I want to add a tweak there, which will add a slight delay between each animation. That way, all the animations in the same line, would appear one by one,  and not all by together at the same time.

My idea was to add a class name, for instance: **delay-1**, and it will add **animate-delay: 1s**; to it.

**Here's a live example of what I want to do. Scroll down and see how "Our Progress" displays each animation with a delay:**

http://demo.qodeinteractive.com/river/home-anchors/#home_presentation

Is this something I can do with CSS3 only? whether the answer is yes or no I would be much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

try to define class like this:

```
.delay-1 {
    animation-delay:1s !important;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1s !important;
}
```

no idea if it will work ...but worth trying
..yes ...it will do the job - it worked for me

Comment: Hi, I am using keyframes. I am trying to keep my div hidden while there's a delay, and display it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CSS3 transition will do the trick , i have a demo page set up long time ago. You can refer to it..

As you can see, the first item has a 2s delay and the second item has no delay. Good Luck

```
#demo:hover {
width: 300px;
transition-delay: 2s
}

#demo1:hover {
width: 300px;
transition-delay: 0s
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zFbkL/

Comment: The CSS3 animations file that I mentioned in my first post is using keyframes, so my target is to have the div in visibility:none; while the delay is in proccess. After the delay, I want it to become visibility:visible again. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You would still need to add a class to the section when you scroll to it via Javascript but you can use `nth-child()` to target each one.

Let's say there's 4 steps you could do:

```
.steps .step:nth-child(1) { transition-delay: 1s; }
.steps .step:nth-child(2) { transition-delay: 2s; }
.steps .step:nth-child(3) { transition-delay: 3s; }
.steps .step:nth-child(4) { transition-delay: 4s; }
```

Though, with an unknown number of steps you're better off scripting this out I think.

```
$('.steps .step').each(function(i){
  $(this).css('animation-delay', i + 's');
});
```

Then, set off the animations by adding a class to `.steps`.

```
.steps .step { trainsition: all 1s; opacity: 0; width: 0;}
.steps.in-view .step { opacity: 1; width: auto; }
```

Hopefully this is what you were aiming for.

Comment: Hi Bill, Thanks for your reply. I am actually using keyframes. My target is to have the div hidden while the animation is on delay, and show it (visibility:visible) after. Is this possible?

Comment: You can't animate visibility. You can animate opacity which is what I have in there.

Comment: I just want the div to stay hidden, and show up when the delay has gone.  Just like in the example.